# Libre Office Impress - Notes not showing on presentation started on MS-Office Powerpoint

Tags: libreoffice, 14.10

Im working on a presentation and last night when testing, i noticed my notes weren't appearing on slides based on a powerpoint template.

I tried inserting a blank slide not based on the same master page, and the notes are working just fine.

I had to use this template because the school requires me to for this final presentations, but without my notes, the slides are close to useless

Anyone has seen this before?

Thanks

Comment: Never seen this before, but what happens if you change to font colour of the notes to let's say dark blue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure what caused the problem (probably using a template from MS-Office), but what solved it was Deleting every text box in the notes and adding new ones, created in Libre.

This way, the notes display correctly

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar issue with the notes in Libre Office Calc. Notes made in Excel or even earlier versions of Libre Office are using MS Sans Serif as standard font. This font is apparently no longer supported in the latest versions of Libre Office (don't know why ?). Any notes or other text written in this font is not displayed by those versions of Libre Office, allthough the text is present.
You can make this text visible again by clicking in the note, pressing +a (select all) and choosing a different font. At least, that's what helps for the Calc notes.

Comment: I can't test it right now, but this sounds accurate. I will post the results on impress if i can test it.